# Django/Apache code not reloading after restart of web server

Tags: python, linux, django, ubuntu

I'm dealing with legacy code on Ubuntu server. I've encountered something weird: after Apache restarts (a full server restart), the site is still using old code, even if views.py was deleted.

Please, provide me some suggestions/tips - what might cause this server behavior?

Comment: Delete the .pyc files

Comment: Did you try delete all `*.pyc` files?

Comment: I dont have them in project/app folders, maybe they can be cached in other unusual places?

Comment: Are you sure that legacy server is not a separate process behind Apache (so it is not actually restarted when you restart Apache)?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. In my case, running the following command solved it :

```
touch myproject/wsgi.py
```

No need to restart server or delete .pyc files. It's all explained in [mod_wsgi docs](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode#Reloading_In_Daemon_Mode).